# MySQL, exclude zero-value POINT with ST_Distance_Sphere

Tags: mysql

I have records with POINT(0,0) value that is actually null by my business logic (because MySQL doesn't allow to have indexes by POINT column with null values).

How to filter out such zero-points in SQL?

Comment: that is not correct newer versions have https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html but there are limits to this

Comment: add add a int column and out 0 for o,o and 1 for the rest and you can add a noral index or use it in an combined index

Comment: @nbk sorry, corrected my question. MySQL doesn't allow indexes on column with null-POINT values.

Comment: @nbk yeah, i thought about this, but thinking about plain SQL without new flags )

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data, i don't think that point(0,0) will be an issue